# pip install pyarrow failing in Linux / Inside a docker

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pyarrow

I tried installing pyarrow and it's failing with the below error. I also tried the option --no-binary :all: and still the same problem. Any help to resolve this will really help me.

Python version: 3.7
Linux version: python:3.7-alpine
Below is the stack trace of the install.

```
**sudo pip install pyarrow --proxy=x.x.x.x.**

*Looking in indexes: https://x.x.x.x/api/pypi/python/simple/
Collecting pyarrow
  Downloading https://repo.lab.pl.alcatel-lucent.com/api/pypi/python/packages/packages/fd/b7/78115614c4b227796cc87fff907930f6ae6dd999c5000d3d6ae5c2e54582/pyarrow-2.0.0.tar.gz (58.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 58.9 MB 55 kB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyarrow) (1.19.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyarrow
  Building wheel for pyarrow (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmp46hjz8zm
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-0fdjam97/pyarrow
  Complete output (555 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python  -DPYARROW_BUILD_CUDA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_FLIGHT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GANDIVA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_DATASET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ORC=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PLASMA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_S3=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_HDFS=off -DPYARROW_USE_TENSORFLOW=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_ARROW_CPP=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_BOOST=off -DPYARROW_GENERATE_COVERAGE=off -DPYARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on -DPYARROW_PARQUET_USE_SHARED=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /tmp/pip-install-0fdjam97/pyarrow
  error: command 'cmake' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly*
```

Answer (score 5):

The most likely guess here is that you are missing `cmake`. As you are probably on a Linux distribution that doesn't support `manylinux` wheels, you need all the build dependencies for `pyarrow` as listed on https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/python.html#using-pip For Ubuntu/Debian, they can be installed using:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install libjemalloc-dev libboost-dev \
                       libboost-filesystem-dev \
                       libboost-system-dev \
                       libboost-regex-dev \
                       python-dev \
                       autoconf \
                       flex \
                       bison
```

Comment: are all these seriously needed just to install pyarrow?

Comment: Nowadays, you need even more libraries when building pyarrow from source. Instead, you should look though why pip is not using a manylinux wheel. There are now even more manylinux flavors available and thus there shouldn't be the need to compile manually from source.